# Having trouble installing libgdiplus

Tags: macos, compilation, mono, powerpc

Make libgdiplus 2.10 results in an error. I am having a hard time finding the cause. It appears to be  a problem with the source file pngcodec.c.

I am not sure if this is a bug or I am just doing something wrong. I would appreciate a suggestion as to where I should look to solve this problem. I am compiling on a powerbook g4 osx leopard 10.5 ppc. I have installed mono, xsp2, and mod_mono successfully from source, but get

```
System.DllNotFoundException: gdiplus.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

when processing aspx file.

So I am trying to install libgdiplus 2.10 but am running up against a wall. I also tried an earlier version of libgdiplus, 2.8 with the same result. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the error I get:

```
pngcodec.c: In function 'gdip_load_png_properties':
pngcodec.c:119: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:119: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:121: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:122: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:137: warning: passing argument 5 of 'png_get_iCCP' from incompatible pointer type
pngcodec.c: In function 'gdip_load_png_image_from_file_or_stream':
pngcodec.c:324: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:325: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:333: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:333: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:333: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:342: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:346: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:346: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:347: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:347: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:350: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:351: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:351: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:351: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:351: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:494: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:494: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:494: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:501: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:501: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:501: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:508: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:508: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:508: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:515: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:515: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
pngcodec.c:515: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
make[2]: *** [pngcodec.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be looking for libgdiplus.dylib?  gdiplus.dll is the windows name. Sounds like you have a broken installation

Comment: Can you post the command lines you used to build mono?

Comment: The pngcodec.c errors looks like a missing/wrong header.

Answer (score 1):

pngcodec.c has some bugs.

I met the same error, but I solved it with info from this link.

http://svnweb.mageia.org/packages/cauldron/libgdiplus/current/SOURCES/libgdiplus-2.10.1-libpng15.patch?revision=142282&view=markup&pathrev=142282